# Regular expression: word between spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

Sry for stupid question, but there is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rb98M/

```
var q = 'SELECT CASE WHEN STATE IN ';
q = q.replace(/(^|\s)\w*(\s|$)/g, function(match) { return match.toLowerCase(); });
alert(q);
```

I have a string and i want to make lowerCase each word, that's between white spaces (and could be in start of line and end).

But, my result is:

`select CASE when STATE in`

and that's my problem. Why is it so?

**Edit** I expect to pass `SELECT * FROM [Users] u` and get `select * from [Users] u` and e.t.c (including each SQL statement and exclude any table names and properties in `[]`)

Comment: I don't get it. What's your expected output?

Comment: Use lookahead and lookbehind for matching spaces.

Comment: @KrzysztofJabłoński: Javascript doesn't have the lookbehind feature.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yup, you're right. Still - in this case - using a single lookahead does the trick: `(^|\s)\w*(?=\s|$)`. Last space won't be consumed by the regex, so it might be consumed as for beginning of another match, thus matching all words with spaces around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are not separating the words with other punctuations. So I believe only using `\S` is sufficient for you.

```
q = q.replace(/(\S+)/g, function(match)
```

In your case it was not working because the \s\w*\s was eating the `SELECT`(with space at end) from the input and the `CASE` wasn't have enough space(`\s`) before it.

Here is how your input was matched using the regex:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN state IN 
^  m1 ^    ^ m2 ^     ^m3^
```

Its just ignored the `CASE` ad the `state` words from the regex. Because the space before the `CASE` was picked by the `SELECT`. You have mandatory space(`\s`) at the both sides of the word(i.e. `\s\w*\s`). In other words your regex has overlapping.

#### Updated regex:

```
q = q.replace(/(?:\s|^)(\w+)(?=\s|$)/g, function(match)
```

Comment: What do you mean about eating? If that's mean substring- then `case` should start from `$ - start line character`. If it's not, then spaces still in a string.

Comment: @FSou1 I have updated my answer. Hope this example will help you to understand this a bit. I am talking about overlapping in your input and regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code and put in the capturing group all parts you want to skip:

```
var q = 'SELECT * FROM [Users] u aNd GeT sElEct * from [Users] U';
q = q.replace(/(\[[^\]]+\])|\w+/g, function(m, g1) {
   return (g1) ? m : m.toLowerCase(); });
```

The method `toLowerCase()` is applied to the whole match only if the capturing group is defined.

I used `\w` to make the pattern shorter, but since it is useless to replace digits, lowercase letters and underscores, you can replace it with `[A-Z]`

pattern detail:

```
\[      # a literal [
[^\]]+  # character class with all characters except ] (repeated one or more times)
\]      # a literal ]
```

Note that you don't need to escape the closing square bracket (or only for very old versions of internet explorer):), you can write: `\[[^]]+]`

Comment: A fancy one. It introduces a branch in the logic however. While it might be a suitable and working solution it's quite difficult to read and understand.

Comment: @KrzysztofJabłoński: "difficult to read", I don't realize, I will add a short description of the first part of the pattern. The advantage of this way is that you can easily costumize it to skip, for example, a string between quotes or whatever you want.

Comment: That's not that much of a problem, but it took me 5 minutes to get the point of your two lines snippet. It took me 20 seconds to get the point of questioner's snippet.

Comment: @KrzysztofJabłoński: don't worry, next time, it will take less than one second.